# React Redux <No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux, cors, react-redux

I'm using React + Redux  + RoR in app. I have to do social login. For client-side I use davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit, and it's located on localhost:3000. My server - localhost:5000. All request from client to server have no problem (PUT,GET,POST). When I try login using twitter (it's work on server, localhost:5000/auth/twitter - create new user in DB with params from twitter) I have an error :

```
Failed to load https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=xxxxx: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

on client-side I call this like:

```
export const requestTest = async () => {
return axios.get('http://localhost:5000/auth/twitter', {}).then(function (response) {
        console.log('cors')
    console.log(response)
    return response.data
})
```

};

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your React dev server origin is differs from Rails application server origin (even just by port number), Rails thinks that request is cross-origin.

When Rails receives such request it denies it unless [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) policy is set up.

The easiest way to do so is (probably) to use [rack-cors](https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors) gem:

1)
Add

```
gem 'rack-cors', require: 'rack/cors'
```

to your `Gemfile`.

2) `bundle install`

3) add

```
# see gem page for more examples
config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins /\Ahttp:\/\/localhost:\d+\z/
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: :any
  end
end
```

in `class Application < Rails::Application` inside your `config/application.rb`.

4) restart rails.

Comment: I develop on one machine and test on others. I've found the easiest method is to use a CORS ignoring browser extension. Warning: I dont think its safe should you leave this switched on for regular browsing.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cors-toggle/jioikioepegflmdnbocfhgmpmopmjkim?hl=en